# Webpack Concating all files in to one with out wrapping any Javascript files

Tags: webpack, import, ecmascript-6, export, rollup

if . I have

In  allImport.js

```
    import { Footer } from './bundle';
    import { xyz } from '../xyz';
```

and I want all class in one file so I can use that as package.

```
export class Footer {

}

export class xyz {

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, The desired end result you want to achieve is not clear.

Comment: @borian I just want to create a bundle of all javascript (Js) files.

Comment: @Borian `   import { Header } from 'core';  `

Comment: so I can import all files into one file and use as whenever I want.  as components bundle

Comment: then you should post your webpack config, have your tried the default https://webpack.js.org/concepts/configuration/#the-simplest-configuration